# Creating a upper slider menu on a page

Tags: android

I am trying to create a search filter at the top of screen which will be like a slider or button slider. Don't know how to do this.

sharing an image

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="in.mega.sliderdrawer.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_close_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/search_close_btn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/at_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:hint="Address, city, airport, ZIP Code"
                    >

                    <requestFocus />

                </EditText>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/from_place"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:hint=""
                        >

                        <requestFocus />

                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>





    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/top_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting in Edittext it is allowed here.
First I am not able to figure out if I am doing it right or not.

Comment: I guess I have to use sliderdrawer as parent wait let me do some work and edit this question

Comment: you can use FrameLayout as parent and add this search view above the lower layout, give some elevation, add some sliding animations and you are good to go.

Comment: what about sliderdrawer shoudnt i use this one ?

Comment: @GauravChauhan look i have added what you have told is it right?

Answer (score 0):

i think for this you can use this library which already does what you want to achieve [AndroidSlidingDownPanel](https://github.com/ArgonMobile/AndroidSlidingDownPanel)

Comment: Please see some code added and problem stated at last and I guess I don't want to use library since the library has a class in which lots of things were done which I guess would take an hour to figure out what's happening therefore please look what need to be done in xml